# Surpress or hide page numbers without losing metropolis theme or miniframes

Tags: beamer, page-numbering, beamer-metropolis, mini-frames

I am building a template presentation in Latex. I want to use the Metropolis beamer theme, as well as the miniframes for cool navigation.

I am trying to put off my page numbers, but I can't find out how to do that.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Table of contents}
    \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
    \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\section{hello}
\begin{frame}{Example}
    Text
\end{frame}
\section{hello 2}
\begin{frame}{Example}
    More text
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Example}
    Even more text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I have tried the following based on other questions:
`\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{bg=white}` to put off page numbering by making it same color as background. Nu clue why but the page numbering was still black.
`\pagenumbering{gobble}` do not know why this should help, but did not work.
`\begin{frame}[plain]` and some other things like that, lost the miniframe navigation bar.

Anyone with ideas? Would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the `metropolis` theme, you could use `moloch`, a more modern fork of `metropolis`. This has the advantage that it does not add frame numbers by default and instead allows the users to add them as needed via the usual `page number in head/foot` template of beamer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Table of contents}
    \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
    \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\section{hello}
\begin{frame}{Example}
    Text
\end{frame}
\section{hello 2}
\begin{frame}{Example}
    More text
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Example}
    Even more text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

#### For the original metropolis theme:

Metropolis does not use the standard `page number in head/foot` template from beamer, but instead uses its own name `frame numbering`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}

\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[none]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Table of contents}
    \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
    \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\section{hello}
\begin{frame}{Example}
    Text
\end{frame}
\section{hello 2}
\begin{frame}{Example}
    More text
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Example}
    Even more text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[none]
is the relevant part

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Can't believe that I missed something this simple. Thank you so much. Works perfectly and does not mess with other parts of my presentation.

Comment: @MarjavanderWind You're welcome!